# Java Stream - Combine Two Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Is there a way I can combine these two streams into one?

Here's the first stream

```
Map<String, String> rawMapping = tokens.getColumnFamilies().stream()
            .filter(family -> family.getName().equals("first_family"))
            .findAny()
            .map(columns -> columns.getColumns().stream()).get()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Column::getPrefix,
                Column::getValue
            ));
```

Second stream

```
List<Token> tokenValues = tokens.getColumnFamilies().stream()
            .filter(family -> family.getName().equals("second_family"))
            .findAny()
            .map(columns -> columns.getColumns().stream()).get()
            .map(token -> {
                return Token.builder()
                    .qualifier(token.getPrefix())
                    .raw(rawMapping.get(token.getPrefix()))
                    .token(token.getValue())
                    .build();
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Basically **tokens** is a list which has two column family, my goal is to create a list which will combine the value of the two-column family based on their **qualifier**. The first stream is storing the first column family into a map. The second stream is traversing the second family and getting the value thru the map using the qualifier and storing it into a new list.

Comment: Sounds like a typical [tag:hbase] construct. But what would be the expected output if you are not able to find the first_family? Or if not able to find the second_family? What if there are different columns under both the column families? You need to specify the details in the question. On the other note, the complexity of any other solution would involve iterating through all the column prefix and value combinations under both the column families and that is what your current solution does as well.

Comment: One layer of abstraction though possible is to perform lookup separrately `class ColumnFamily{List<Column> columns;}
    class Column { String prefix;String value;}

    public void actualMethod() {
        Optional<ColumnFamily> firstFamily = columnFamilyLookUp("first_family");
        Optional<ColumnFamily> secondFamily = columnFamilyLookUp("second_family");
    }

    Optional<ColumnFamily> columnFamilyLookUp(String nameOfFamily){
        return tokens.getColumnFamilies().stream()
            .filter(family -> family.getName().equals(nameOfFamily))
            .findAny();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

you can use double filtering and then later you might use a flat map then to get a list:

```
Map<String, String> tokenvalues =    tokens.getColumnFamilies().stream()
          .filter(family -> family.getName().equals("first_family"))
           .filter(family -> family.getName().equals("second_family"))
          .map(columns -> columns.getColumns().stream())
       //etc..
.stream()
      .flatMap(Collection::stream)
      .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

you can remake a stream out of it inline

https://www.baeldung.com/java-difference-map-and-flatmap